# using oauth in laravel gives Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: laravel, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

i want to add google oauth to my laravel project using socialite package. i create a project in google developer console with address

> http://lvh.me

which is localhost. and for callback url i add this:

> http://lvh.me:8000/login/google/callback

and i added the routes and functions to my project and authController. now when i hit the address

> http:lvh.me:8000/login/google

it returns for me the error:

> Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
>
> The redirect URI in the request, https://lvh.me:8000/login/google/callback, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect URIs

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This means that the `redirect_uri` you sent in the OAuth request doesn't match the one you have registered in the Google Cloud Console. Check and see whether either of them are wrong. They should be the same.